# How to get new FacebookSDKAccessToken before it has been expired?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have iPhone application with an functionality of Login with facebook including few other functionalities related to graph API.
I receives facebook access token and save it to the server and server then makes further requests to graph API call from web end. As facebook access token expires after 60 days, I am getting access token expired error.

To solve this issue can i use FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken method to get new Access token ?
I did not find any clear idea for FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken.

OR Is there any other way to get new access token by performing automatic login with facebook from our application.

Thanks.

Comment: [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) can help

Comment: Yes, using facebook sdk.

Comment: access token expired error you are getting from your server or facebook SDK?

Comment: not directly from facebook sdk. actually i have saved it on server and from server side we have made requests to the graph API. but after 60 days the access token stored on server is getting expired.

Answer (score 1):

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access
>   tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once
>   per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's
>   servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60
>   days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to
>   get a new token.

From the FB docs. ^

It seems the user will have to go through the login process in the app once again.

Comment: Yes, user will have to go through login process after 60 days or after token has been expired. From the same document i found that we can also get new long lived token from server end by making calls to Facebook server.
Still I have a question, If long-lived access token got from previous auth is already expired on server, can we get new long lived token from that token?